# Rebasing master onto feature branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I recently joined a new team and on the team wiki, it asks us to do the follow git workflow

```
git checkout -b feature_branch
#do stuff and push if needed
git checkout master
git rebase feature_branch
git rebase -i HEAD~NUMBER_OF_COMMITS_AHEAD
```

This is different from the rebase workflow I've seen on basically all sources and it also seems to go against the golden rule of rebasing that I saw from this blog post https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing. Can someone explain what could be the reasons for the workflow my team wiki suggests?

Comment: In the excerpt you shared something very interesting is shown. I would not do like that ever. Instead, `git pull --rebase origin master` is quite good tool to begin with.

Comment: This seems backwards. Maybe it's just a typo (or multiple typos)? Have you asked any team members if they actually do this?

Comment: It looks weird indeed. Ask your team

Comment: Not quite sure seeing this for the first time. Rebasing feature branch with master locally is not a common scenario. Generally, once the feature branch changes are reviewed and merged we pull it down from remote. Let us know whats the use-case for the above guidelines.

Comment: It sounds like whoever wrote that wiki needs to take a few hours to learn how git works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the instructions are accurate, they would appear to be executing a splice of `feature` into `master`. Suppose we start with this:

```
* (HEAD -> master) E
* D
| * (feature) K
| * J
|/  
* C
* B
* A
```

Now if we checkout `master` and `rebase feature`, we get this:

```
* (HEAD -> master) E
* D
* (feature) K
* J
* C
* B
* A
```

So the entirety of `feature` has been incorporated into `master` at the point where it split off from `master`. Subsequent commits on `master` have been moved into the future so that they come after the end of `feature`. J and K are spliced into the history A, B, C [splice], D, E.

It's hard to imagine what the purpose of that would be, and it's even harder to imagine what the interactive rebase at the end is supposed to accomplish.

The opposite move, however, namely to checkout `feature` and `rebase master`, would give us this:

```
* (feature) K
* J
* (HEAD -> master) E
* D
* C
* B
* A
```

That is a sensible thing to do. It brings `feature` up to date with the current state of `master`, minimizing the likelihood of conflicts later. And the interactive rebase would then make sense too, because that's your chance to clean up `feature`. You would then push `feature` and make a pull request. That is the flow that is generally followed.

So my guess is that the instructions are just a mistake. It's an easy mistake to make if you're not careful, because the sense of the operations `checkout X; merge Y` is the opposite of the sense of the operations `checkout X; rebase Y`. The former means "merge Y into X", but the latter means "rebase X onto Y". I'll bet whoever wrote the instructions was confused by that.

Comment: This is honestly exactly what I had in mind as well. Turns out it was just more of a guideline, we don't need to follow it strictly. I guess it could very well be a typo. Thanks for thorough answer.